# My external LED not showing the correct resolution as my laptop resolution

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution

My laptop resolution is 1600*900 but on my external LED screen it is showing 1024*768. I attached the LED screen with a VGA cable. I just install Ubuntu 18.04. Before updating it was working but after the update, it does not work properly.

Comment: welcome to ask ubuntu. Please avoid posting screenshots of text. If you have the text please post so that. It allows others to debug without having to retype what you have. Also, in cases like this, you should provide a little information about your hardware ( I can see some in the computer name but better to be explicit )

Comment: LED screen? one LED is a single light.

Comment: yes LED screen of 20 inch ..

Comment: On external LED screen its stucks on 1024*768 but on laptop its shows the original pixel.. please help ..